# Best way to use Assertion in Page Object Model (POM)?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I m Using following assertion to read the validation message in POM but sometimes testcases may give different Validation message which makes TestCase fail , i want to get that Validation message if the testcase fails so that i can debug easily

```
     // Assert whether Account Created Successfully or Not

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr/td/font"));
    String strngAcc = element.getText();
    System.out.println(strngAcc);
    Assert.assertEquals("    Account Information Created Successfully", strngAcc);
```

If the Validation got was "Account Already exists" , the Testcase fails indicating that

```
xpath could not found //html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr/td/font
```

i want to capture that validation "Account Already exists" .

please provide me a way to pick the validation actually displaying

PS : I Dont want to go with Screen Shot Capture method

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use xpaths that are too literal in the placement in the html code because by doing this, your tests become brittle and can easily break (e.g. if the structure of the dom changes a bit).

It sounds like the xpath of the correct validation message and "Account Already exists" message are different...What does the structure of the elements look like in html? Again, your xpath may be too specific. Could you give more info?

Comment: Yea. xpath of the correct validation message and "Account Already exists" message are different but the testcase is to create account and assert **Account created successfully** but sometimes the testcase may fail indicating **assertion error** because of Display of different Validation message.i don't know what caused the testcase to fail as there are so many **validation messages** like **Account already Exists** or **Account name is not valid** and so on. Can i catch the Validation Appeared **Actually** instead of **Expected["Account created successfully"]** so that i can debug the testcase

Comment: You could....but the xpath of all those messages must share a base structure. If the error messages share the same xpaths, you could put the code in a try/catch block. In the try you put the code to find the correct one, and in the catch you find the xpath of the error message and output the error message--if the xpath of all error messages is the same it wouldn't matter which error message.

Comment: That is the Perfect way if all the Errors share a common xpath but is there any way to pick up what message is Displaying on the Screen

Comment: boolean b = driver.getPageSource().contains("account created successfully"); assertTrue(b); returns **True** if Page contains that Message. Is there Any way to Pick what is Displaying in the Page without the Use of contains.

Comment: By doing 
boolean b = driver.getPageSource().contains("account created successfully");
you're making web driver search the entire page, and you need to use contains if you plan to do this, to search if some sort of text you don't care where is on that page.

It would be best to use xpath...I know you said you don't want to use screenshot, but if the xpaths for all the error messages are not the same, the only other alternative other than screenshot is to have your code in a try/catch block, expect the different error messages in a try/catch block...gosh that's so painful...

Comment: You are Right . The only way to do it is Surrounding **Assertions** with Try Catch block . Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't the assertion, it's fact that WebDriver cannot find the element it's looking for with that xpath.

Rather than using this absolute XPath, you should look for better ways to find the element you're looking for. Do any of the elements the validation error have specific ID's that you can search for? You'll have to post a snippet of the HTML if you want any more specific help than that.

Comment: @ Steve - you are right but i wanted to check for "Account created successfully" using above mentioned xpath(if condition). if the Message was "Account Already Exists" then get that text (else condition) without use of xpath. something kind of "PAGE SOURCE GET TEXT " ... is that possible ??

Comment: @METIsatish It's definitely going to be possible, but you'll have to post a snippet of the html you're searching through (for both cases 'Account created successfully' and 'Account Already Exists') for me to help any more than that. You should read up on XPath selectors, I think you'll find they can do a lot more than you're aware of

Comment: @ Steve - The Expected Result is 'Account created successfully'  when i run my testcase and i have used xpath to capture it but sometimes due to duplication account name the validation may come as "Account Already Exists" or "invalid account name" which is random . Is there any way to capture that kind of validation messages so that i can know where my testcase has failed ?

Comment: @ Steve - when i run my testcase , if there is an Existing Account name , the validation message will be "Account Already Exists" but since i have used xpath of 'Account created successfully' , the testcase fail indicating **Assertion error** by which i don't know whether the validation was **"Account Already Exists" or "invalid account name"**.

Comment: lastexile's comment says it all. Use try/catch blocks to handle the different scenarios.